# Testing Optional equivalence with FluentAssertions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions, option-type

I'm using a library called `Optional` (https://github.com/nlkl/Optional) that allows the "maybe" abstraction that is common to functional languages.

The library is awesome, but I'm facing a problem regarding testing: I can't test correctly whether 2 optional instances are equivalent or not.

To test for equivalence I'm using [Fluent Assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/). However, I'm not getting the desired results.

I will illustrate the problem with code:

```
#load "xunit"

[Fact]
void TestOptional()
{
    var a = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Some();
    var b = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Some();
    
    a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(b);
}
```

This test fails, as I show in the screenshot (I'm using LINQPad, for convenience)

[image]

As you see, this isn't what one expects.

How do I tell Fluent Assertions to check the equivalence correctly using the Option type?

Comment: Maybe this will be a little help: `a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(b, opt => opt.ComparingByMembers<Option<int[]>>());` not sure how to make it more generic and setup it globally though.

Comment: Also, you mean `{ 1, 2, 3 } = { 1, 3, 2 }` and not `{ 1, 2, 3 } = { 1, 3, 3 }`?

Comment: @MichaelSchnerring Thanks for noticing :) Fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### UPDATE

[I opened an issue on Github](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/1388) regarding your problem and yesterday a [pull request was merged](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/pull/1389), so the next (pre-)release should enable you to solve your problem elegantly:

> The new overloads allows you to use an open generic type.
> If both an open and closed type are specified, the closed type takes precedence.

`SelfReferenceEquivalencyAssertionOptions` adds the following methods:

- `public TSelf ComparingByMembers(System.Type type) { }`
- `public TSelf ComparingByValue(System.Type type) { }`

[Here's the unit test](https://github.com/jnyrup/fluentassertions/blob/5922af800aeeb589e0e33483989fd2006af959eb/Tests/FluentAssertions.Specs/Equivalency/BasicEquivalencySpecs.cs#L379) that was added to Fluent Assertions showing how it works:

```
[Fact]
public void When_comparing_an_open_type_by_members_it_should_succeed()
{
    // Arrange
    var subject = new Option<int[]>(new[] { 1, 3, 2 });
    var expected = new Option<int[]>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });

    // Act
    Action act = () => subject.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, opt => opt
        .ComparingByMembers(typeof(Option<>)));

    // Assert
    act.Should().NotThrow();
}
```

---

[Fluent Assertions - Object Graph Comparison](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/) says:

> **Value Types**
>
> To determine whether Fluent Assertions should recurs into an object’s
> properties or fields, it needs to understand what types have value
> semantics and what types should be treated as reference types. The
> default behavior is to treat every type that **overrides Object.Equals
> as an object that was designed to have value semantics**. Unfortunately,
> anonymous types and tuples also override this method, but because we
> tend to use them quite often in equivalency comparison, we always
> compare them by their properties.
>
> You can easily override this by using the `ComparingByValue<T>` or
> `ComparingByMembers<T>` options for individual assertions

`Option<T>` is a `struct` and overrides `Equals`, so Fluent Assertions compares `a` and `b` with value semantics.

`Option<T>` implements `Equals` like this:

```
public bool Equals(Option<T> other)
{
  if (!this.hasValue && !other.hasValue)
    return true;
  return this.hasValue
    && other.hasValue 
    && EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(this.value, other.value);
}
```

Thus `int[]` is compared by reference and your test fails.

You can override this behavior for each test individually, like [Guro Stron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2501279/guru-stron) said:

```
a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(b, opt => opt.ComparingByMembers<Option<int[]>>());
```

Or globally via static `AssertionOptions` class:

```
AssertionOptions.AssertEquivalencyUsing(options => 
    options.ComparingByMembers<Option<int[]>>());
```

**edit:**

For your case Fluent Assertions would need an `AssertEquivalencyUsing` override that supports unbound generic types:

```
AssertionOptions.AssertEquivalencyUsing(options => 
    options.ComparingByMembers(typeof(Option<>)));
```

No such override exists, unfortunately.

Another solution a came up with would be an extension method. Here a very simplistic implementation:

```
public static class FluentAssertionsExtensions
{
    public static void BeEquivalentByMembers<TExpectation>(
        this ComparableTypeAssertions<TExpectation> actual,
        TExpectation expectation)
    {
        actual.BeEquivalentTo(
            expectation,
            options => options.ComparingByMembers<TExpectation>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is still a far from ideal solution. It means that I will have to configure every different type of collection I'd want to handle. I mean, if want it to work with List<string>, I need to explicitly add the line above for List<string>, right?

Comment: Yes, you would need to add that line. In your case it may be undesired but in other cases it isn't - there isn't an ideal solution.

Comment: @SuperJMN check my updated answer for another solution I came up with.

Comment: @SuperJMN Updated my post again. Yesterday a PR was merged, that adds support for open generic types.